# Given $n$ cells and $r$ balls, estimate the probability of finding $m$ or more cells empty

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15713/probability-of-finding-m-or-more-cells-empty) is already asked here 9 years ago. But unfortunately, it is not answered (nor confirmed as a typo).  The question is from the classic texbook "An introduction to probability theory" by William Feller.  The question want us to prove that

$x_m(r,n)$, the probability of finding $m$ or more cells empty is

$$
\binom{n}{m}\sum_{\nu=0}^{n-m}(-1)^{\nu}\binom{n-m}{\nu}\left(1-\frac{m+\nu}{n}\right)^{r}\frac{m}{m+v}
$$

Any help ?

Comment: Is that supposed to say "$m$ or more" cells?

Comment: @RobertShore. Yes, In fact exact $m$ cells is relatively easy to estimate.

Comment: I was pointing out a typo, which I've fixed now that you've confirmed that it was, in fact, a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general inclusion/exclusion formula for the probability that $m$ or more of the events $A_1, \dots , A_n$ occur simultaneously is
$$P_m = \sum_{\nu = 0}^{n-m} (-1)^{\nu} \binom{m+\nu-1}{m-1} S_{m+\nu}$$
where $S_1 = \sum_i P(A_i)$, $S_2 = \sum_{ij} P(A_i A_j)$, $S_3 = \sum_{ijk} P(A_i A_j A_k)$ etc.

(Reference: Equation 5.2 in section IV.5 of *An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications, Third Edition* by William Feller)

In the case of $r$ balls in $n$ cells with $A_i$ being the event that cell $i$ is empty, we have
$$S_{\nu} = \binom{n}{\nu} \left( 1 - \frac{\nu}{n} \right)^r$$
for $0 \le \nu \le n$, so
$$x_m(r,n) = \sum_{\nu = 0}^{n-m} (-1)^{\nu} \binom{m+\nu-1}{m-1} \binom{n}{m+\nu} \left( 1 - \frac{m+\nu}{n} \right)^r$$
Now apply the identity
$$\binom{m+\nu-1}{m-1} \binom{n}{m+\nu} = \binom{n}{m} \binom{n-m}{\nu} \frac{m}{m+\nu}$$
and we have
$$x_m(r,n) = \binom{n}{m} \sum_{\nu=0}^{n-m} (-1)^{\nu} \binom{n-m}{\nu}  \left( 1 - \frac{m+\nu}{n} \right)^r \frac{m}{m+\nu}$$