# Ball / Urn question with a twist

Tags: probability

I am trying to answer questions like:   We select, with replacement, $20$ balls from an urn holding $30$ numbered balls.  What is the probability that we have selected at least $15$ distinct balls?

The general form is: An urn contains $m$ balls, numbered $1$ to $m$. We select $n$ balls with replacement $(n ≤ m)$.  What is the probability that we have selected AT LEAST $k$ distinct balls $(k ≤ m)$?

There are related questions on this site, but I'm not sure how to handle the 'AT LEAST' part.

Comment: This is similar to the coupon collector problem, but you don't need all the different balls.

Answer (score 2):

The following problem is equivalent.

Suppose we have $n$ bins and $r$ balls.  We toss the balls into the bins independently, with all bins being equally likely to receive a ball.  Let's say that in general $x_m(n,r)$ is the probability that at least $m$ bins are empty.  Then the answer to the original problem is $1-x_{16}(30,20)$, since having at least $15$ cells selected is equivalent to having $15$ or fewer cells empty, and the complementary event is that there are $16$ or more empty cells.

The only difficulty that remains is how to calculate $x_m(n,r)$, and a recent question gives the answer via the principle of inclusion and exclusion.  See [Given $n$ cells and $r$ balls, estimate the probability of finding $m$ or more cells empty](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3762253/given-n-cells-and-r-balls-estimate-the-probability-of-finding-m-or-more-c#3762253).  (The problem title is misleading, since the result is exact, not an estimate.) At the risk of being repetitious, the answer is
$$x_m(r,n) = \binom{n}{m} \sum_{\nu=0}^{n-m} (-1)^{\nu} \binom{n-m}{\nu}  \left( 1 - \frac{m+\nu}{n} \right)^r \frac{m}{m+\nu}$$

If we evaluate this formula with $n=30$, $r=20$, and $m=16$, we find
$$1-x_{16}(30,20) \approx 0.577467$$